# Error "Could not find a valid session key" after contributions are made

Tags: wordpress, contributions, contribution-page, session

Recently in the past we did do a migration from a development site to production and I'm not sure if we were having the issue before migration or not. Every time someone makes a contribution they receive the error:

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
> moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
> with more details about what action you were performing when this
> occurred. We can't load the requested web page. This page requires
> cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this
> setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again.
> If this error persists, contact the site administrator for
> assistance.
> Site Administrators: This error may indicate
> that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than
> the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but
> some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a
> domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.
> Error type:
> Could not find a valid session key.

- I've checked resource URL's and they appear to be correct.
- I've scrubbed all trace of the old CMS DB and base dev URL from the civi settings file and replaced them with production
- The base URL in Civi and WordPress are matching besides a final / that civi has on it's base URL (I tried removing this but made no difference to changed it back
- I have looked through everything relating to this issue on the stack exchange and have not found anything that worked

If anyone can help me with this I will be forever in your debt.

EDIT:
Okay guys after a billion hours of searching, trying things, and changing things I THINK that I have MOSTLY resolved the issue. I THINK what I did to resolve it is .... I realized that it was linking to development CMS DB (they both use same civi DB but different WordPress CMS DB).

After making this change I was able to make contributions in incognito mode and using another browser.... next I tried chrome (the same browser I've been using all along) and got the error. I cleared all cache in chrome, tried again while not logged into WordPress as admin, and it worked.

Next I logged into WordPress as admin and got the error. Deleted my chrome cache and tried again while logged in as admin and got the error.

Then I deleted all cache files in template_c directory and while logged into WordPress as administrator I successfully made a contribution! Then I tried a second time and got the error.

So I think it is working for all new users contributing ... but gives me the error if I'm logged into WordPress as administrator, unless I delete the cache in the template_c directory each time.

Hopefully that makes sense and someone can lead me to the last piece in the puzzle / figure out what is causing this.

Comment: For this kind of troubleshooting I might try https://chat.civicrm.org in the wordpress channel and link to your post so they know what you've already tried.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I'm gonna go there right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue documented here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1997  Fixes have been merged into 5.30 branch https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18525 and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18534

So you can apply the patches, or wait until the 5.30 release in early October.

Comment: Thank you so much - this was the issue and your reply saved me a billion hours of banging my head against the wall.